# Calling a method from the getter of a property

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

Is there a way I can define a method, that is called in every case, when a getter for any property in a class is called?

The class is a base class, and I want to implement various SubClasses of it, but each one should have in common that regardless of the property that should be accessed by its getter function, an action should be performed before the attribute is returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not unless you code it into every Getter, or you abandon "Plain Old C# Classes" altogether and construct a data model paradigm based around a read-audited set of data. If you go down that route that you simply have each "data class" being an Dictionary of Get/Set delegates and access its data values through those delegates. Its not an uncommon design, but it no longer follows the OO paradigms.

Example (psuedo code)

```
public class MonitoredCustomerObject
{
    // Assumption that the Get/Set delegates are stored in a simple Tuple.
    private Dictionary<string, Tuple<delegate,delegate>> getterSetterDict = new ...

    public GetValue(string key)
    {
        executeMyOnReadCode();
        return getterSetterDict[key].Item1();
    }

    public SetValue(string key)
    {
        executeMyOnWriteCode();
        getterSetterDict[key].Item2();
    }
}
```

Comment: This helps a lot :) Maybe I will rather stick to OO principles, and until no other solution is found, I try to reduce the calls to when they are essentially needed or implement them manually. But good to see that there's another approach which is not uncommon.

Comment: @fruitx this is how the .net framework Expando Objects are implemented 'under the hood'. Because this kind of design allows you to remove and add 'fields' to the 'class' at runtime, it bridges the gap between loosely typed languages and more 'advanced' OO implementations which allow inheritence deletion and runtime dynamic classes. Its something to consider but should not be rushed into - you need a really good undersanding of the balance between the benefit of POCO and this kind of data dictionary driven business object model.

Answer (score 0):

You can kind of fake this, or you can write a Fody extension that does it. For example, you can have your base class defined as:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public object MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            RunSomeMethod();
            return MyPropertyValue;    
        }
    }
    protected abstract object MyPropertyValue { get; }
}
```

Which "kind of" forces the implementer to write it like:

```
public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass 
{
    protected override object MyPropertyValue
    {
        get
        {
            return SomeObjectValue();
        }
    }
}
```

The derived class can still hide the base class properties with `new`, but at least that causes the developer to explicitly realize that they are doing something unintended.

Comment: It will be worth a try too! My intention is to have DataObjects without actually knowing what's in them, so the dictionary approach maybe more suited. But thanks for your insights.